# How to compute the expectation of integral of this random function?

Tags: stochastic-processes, itos-lemma

Let $W_t$ be a standard wiener process and

$$Y_t=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{W_s}{(1+W_s^2)^2}ds$$

If $W(t_0)=\sqrt{3}$, then how can we compute $\mathbb{E}[Y(t_0)]$?

Is $\mathbb{E}[Y(t_0)]=0$?

Comment: 1. This is not an Itô integral. 2. If $W(t_0)=\sqrt{3}$ clearly $W_t $ is not a standard Wiener process. So are you sure of your question?

Comment: $t_0\ne 0$ yes I sure

Comment: Okay then, my bad.

Comment: Please pay attention to typos and grammar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**1.** This integral is not Ito's Integral. Indeed  $Y_t$ is a random time change with time change rate $\frac{W_t}{1+W_t^2}.$ (Oksendal, Sixth edition,page 147)

**2.** Sometimes this trick is useful.Indeed we assume that we are going to solve Riemann integral !.

Let $$f''(x)=\frac{-2x}{(1+x^2)^2}$$
then
$$f'(x)=\left(\frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)+c_1$$
and
$$f(x)=\tan^{-1}(x)+c_1x+c_2$$
set $c_1=c_2=0$.By application of Ito's lemma we have
$$f(W_t)=f(W_0)+\int_{0}^{t}f'(W_s)dW_s+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{t}f''(W_s)ds$$
therefore
$$\tan^{-1}(W_t)=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{1+W_s^2}dW_s-\int_{0}^{t}\frac{W_s}{(1+W_s^2)^2}ds$$
in other words
$$\int_{0}^{t}\frac{W_s}{(1+W_s^2)^2}ds=\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{1+W_s^2}dW_s-\tan^{-1}(W_t)$$
thus
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{t}\frac{W_s}{(1+W_s^2)^2}ds\right]=\underbrace{\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{t}\frac{1}{1+W_s^2}dW_s\right]}_{0}-\mathbb{E}[\tan^{-1}(W_t)]$$
as a result
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{t}\frac{W_s}{(1+W_s^2)^2}ds\right]=-\mathbb{E}[\tan^{-1}(W_t)]$$
Now set $t=t_0$
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\int_{0}^{t_0}\frac{W_s}{(1+W_s^2)^2}ds\right]=-\mathbb{E}[\tan^{-1}(W_{t_0})]=-\mathbb{E}[\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{3})]=-\frac{\pi}{3}$$
finally

> $$ \color{red}{\mathbb{E}[Y_{t_0}]=-\frac{\pi}{3}}$$